# Why does Intellij Heap Memory Leak on Hello World with Thread.Sleep?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory-leaks, jconsole

I noticed that heap memory usage was increasing on other programs,
so I made this simple program to see if JConsole was reporting the same on simple HelloWorld application. I added a Thread.sleep() in a loop to keep the app alive for testing.

What is the source of this problem? Should I be concerned?

This chart shows my testing setup:

[image]

Here is the code I am using for testing:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            System.out.print("Sleeping...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Working");
    }
}
}
```

This chart shows that the heap memory doubles within 15 minutes:

[image]

After 25 minutes I did see reclaimed memory but the same leak continued from there:

[image]

Is this just the way intellij behaves? Is the reclaimed memory enough to say this is not a leak?

Note: System is macOS High Sierra on MacBook Pro 2.8GHz 16 GB. IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.

Comment: That's entirely normal; heap memory is allowed to accumulate until garbage collection is invoked, which frees some of it up.

Comment: The management console you are using is creating garbage. If you reduce your sampling rate it will increase less.  For finding a memory leak, only look at the memory consumption after a full GC.

Comment: Using `jstat` instead which creates far less garbage.

Comment: @Peter Interesting note on reducing sampling rate. I will check that out. Also, I will check jstat as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacob I think I understand the lifecycle, but garbage collection is unpredictable and it still does not point to the source of the increased memory allocations. Maybe it does not matter. As you say, it may be entirely normal.

Comment: @Peter It is hard to understand that JConsole itself is creating garbage that distorts its representation of memory usage in the target program. This would invalidate its effectiveness across all testing unless it was negligible. Can you clarify what you mean by reducing the sampling rate? I have looked at the memory after GC and it seems stable.

Comment: @Geodepe JConsole is written in Java and so it creates objects to operate like any other Java application.  For my purposes, which is low GC applications, it's useless for the reasons you outlined. It uses Java Serialization is particularly poor for performance/garbage.  However, for most web applications which are actively being used, JConsole's garbage is dwarfed by the garbage the application is producing so it doesn't make a noticable difference.

Comment: @Geodepe BTW Java mission control is much better all round for profiling (though not continous monitoring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jacob suggested, this is entirely normal.

As Peter suggested, I tested with Java Mission Control and verified that the heap memory after successive garbage collections was fairly stable (It would be nice if I could hover over those lows to get exact values).

I still am concerned that such a small test program allocates 140MB on a regular basis. I would have expected something much much lower.

Here is JMC screenshot with findings:

[image]